# The retain cycle with block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, retain-cycle

A question about the retain cycle with block. In the ARC Model.

Say, an instance of view controller named 'vc', it holds reference to a block. Within the block, vc is used for some action :

```
{

    //this is a piece of code snippet in vc
    self.vcBlock = {

        [self someAction];

    }

}
```

I understand that this leads to retain cycle , because vc holds a strong reference to the block while the block will hold a strong reference to vc as well.

But how about referencing a member variable of vc whithin the block:

```
{

    //this is a piece of code snippet in vc
    self.vcBlock = {

        [self.obj someAction];

    }

}
```

Does this cause retain cycle? I think that the relationship of these references can be expained as below:

[image]

So, I think there is no retain cycle exists, any problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `self.obj` is evaluated at runtime, which requires the block to maintain the value of `self`, so you still have a cycle.

However, if your diagram is the relationship you want, that is that your block has a reference to the object which was referenced by `self.obj` *at the time the block is created* then you can simply achieve this by using a temporary local variable. I.e. code along the lines of:

```
SomeType objRef = self.obj;
self.vcBlock = ^{ ... [objRef someAction]; ... };
```

This avoids the cycle as the *value* (an object reference) returned by `self.obj` is first copied into the local `objRef`, and then that *value* becomes part of the block's saved values (aka its *environmemt*).

This is a common approach in this kind of situation, but remember if the value of `self.obj` changes before the block is executed then that change will **not** be seen by the block - which seems to be what you wish from your diagram.

Also note that a cycle *per se* is not a problem, you can create cycles and later break them without issue - indeed it is not uncommon. A cycle is only a problem if it results in unreclaimed resources (like memory).

HTH

Answer (score 3):

Property access is translated to method calls at compile time, so in your second example, it's still self that is retained, and you have exactly the same loop.

Comment: You mean : Obj *obj = [self getObjc]; [obj someAction];  ?

Comment: Something like that, though unless you have a `getter=myGetter` attribute in the property declaration, the method will have the same name as the property.  The setter will be `setObj`, in your example.

Comment: Also, be aware that using the instance variable directly (`_obj`) won't help you.  That still retains `self`, because `_obj` is a struct member, and ARC won't (can't) retain at the struct level.

Answer (score 1):

It does exist retain cycle, vcBlock holds a strong reference to self(the vc),
or you can take it as

```
[[self obj] someAction];
```

if we call this method in another form like this (if the obj is a ivar)

```
[_obj someAction];//in fact ,it's equivalent to [self->obj someAction]
```

so the block always holds a strong reference to self.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, you can avoid the retain cycle:

```
{
    MyObject* obj = self.obj;
    self.vcBlock = ^{ [obj someAction]; };
}
```